# FETCH API - Cannot access property from JSON response in api Request - Array is Empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch-api

I've been trying to run a script that basically:

1. Loops thru a list of SellerIDs and identify how many records (which are product offers) each one has. Then, it creates an object with the Seller ID, Total Number of Pages and Total Number of Records.
2. Loop thru each ID in this newly created object and fetches all offers from each sellers. It fetches in batches of 50, because the API limit = 50.

Later on, I want to save these records to a database. But, to do that, I'm going to save specific properties from each offer.

As I fetched them in batches, I need to access the single offers that are laying in the results property, inside each object. `response.results`.

For some reason, the results field always return as an empty array and I'm unable to reach any of its properties.

If anyone has any idea what could be causing this issue, it's be a great help!
I've been trying to figure out and reading a lot, but still couldn't find out.

I'm a newly starting coding enthusiast, so sometimes I make dumb mistakes :X

Here's the code:

```js
// node --max-old-space-size=8192 '.\2. CheckNeededPagination.js'
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
let listOfSellerIds = require('./1. list_of_seller_ids');
const request = require('request-promise');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Request = require('request');

// IDs do app no Mercado Livre
var meli = require('mercadolibre-nodejs-sdk');
const mlToken = "hidden for security purposese";
const mlAppID = 'hidden for security purposese';
const mlSecretKey = 'hidden for security purposese';
const mlRedirectURI = 'https://localhost:3001/index'
const authURL = `http://auth.mercadolivre.com.br/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${mlAppID}&redirect_uri=${mlRedirectURI}`
const endpoint = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?seller_id='
const reqHeaders = {method: "GET", headers: {'Authorization': mlToken}};
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const myCode = (()=>{
const myPaginationNeeds = [];  

// MODULE 1: Get Pagination Need from All sellers and return them as an object
async function makeRequest(){
      for (s=0; listOfSellerIds[s]; s++){
        const res = await fetch(`https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?seller_id=${listOfSellerIds[s]}&offset=0&limit=1`, {method: "GET", headers: {'Authorization': mlToken}});
        const data = await res.json();
        myPaginationNeeds.push({'SellerID': listOfSellerIds[s],'RecordsNum': await data.paging.total, 'NumOfPages': await Math.ceil(data.paging.total/50)});
  //  myPaginationNeeds.push(await data);
    }

console.log(myPaginationNeeds);   // Uncomment to test object with seller pagination needs

}; // End of MODULE 1

  //MODULE 2 -> Get All Offers From Sellers
  async function getOffers (){
  allOffers = [];
  for (s=0; listOfSellerIds.length > s; s++){ //Loop thru sellers
    curSellerID = listOfSellerIds[s];
    console.log(`We're on seller ${listOfSellerIds[s]}! There are ${listOfSellerIds.length - s} sellers left to go...` )
      for (i =0; 2 > i; i++){ //myPaginationNeeds[s].NumOfPages
        console.log(`We're on page number ${i} of ${myPaginationNeeds[s].NumOfPages}! There are ${myPaginationNeeds[s].NumOfPages - i} pages left to go...` )
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/search?seller_id=${listOfSellerIds[s]}&offset=${myPaginationNeeds[s].NumOfPages*50}&limit=50`, {method: "GET", headers: {'Authorization': mlToken}})
        const resData = await response.json();
        allOffers.push({'SellerInfo': await resData.seller,'SellerPaging': await resData.paging,'SellerResults': await resData.results});
        const myResults = await resData.results[0];
        console.log(await myResults);
        }; // End of loop thru offset
    } // End of loop thru sellers
   // console.log(await allOffers);
    //console.log(allOffers);
  } // end of GetOffers
async function fetchIt () {
  await makeRequest();
  await getOffers();
  console.log(allOffers.length);
  //console.log(allOffers[0].SellerResults[0]);
  };
fetchIt();
}); // End of myCode

myCode();
```

Comment: `for (s=0; listOfSellerIds[s]; s++)`  that isn't how you write a for loop to iterate an array. Any _falsy_ value in the array will break the loop

Comment: Hey @Phil, thanks! Any idea how I could iterate the array and avoid it stopping due to falsy values?

Should I just make sure there are no falsy values in the array or is there any logic I could aply to the loop to prevent it from breaking in falsy values?

Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: `for (let s = 0; s < listOfSellerIds.length; s++)`